# How can I be sure if my grandfather's money is safe?

Tags: united-states, new-york, security, financial-advisor

Years ago, my grandfather sold an old apartment and opened an investment account with a financial advisor he knew from his neighbourhood.

The financial advisor works with a broker and my grandfather can see his money in the Pershing webpage, but I can't find any data about the financial advisor.

A Google search comes back with just a LinkedIn profile.

Is the Pershing account proof of safety?

Is my grandfather's money safe?

Pershing LLC is a subsidiary of The Bank of New York Mellon.

My grandfather is in Uruguay, as are the advisor and the brokerage firm.

Comment: "I can't find any data about this advisor he has".  That's worrisome.  Is your grandfather's account balance growing?  While down this year, it should have doubled in the past 10 years.  That'll tell you **something** about this adviser.

Comment: Not at all. Avg 5% a year. Still, it could be it's just invested in short bonds I guess. I am not concerned about the approach at this moment, but if the money can be stolen in any way without his sign/consent.

Comment: I can see the funds invested and their price at the buy. Still.. Same concern.

Comment: I'm not sure we can really help you more than what you've already done. You need to express your concerns directly to your grandfather.  (Though that's easier said than done.)

Comment: Thanks Ron. Now let's say he trust this man but still I convince him to do further research. What else could we do?

Comment: @Luis "Not at all" -- well, doubling in 10 years is 7% per year, so not quite as big a difference as it may sound.

Comment: Convincing an older man who doesn't have any interest in "finance" (why else would he have given responsibility to the other guy) will be... difficult, especially when there have been no signs of foul play.

Comment: I guess he thought finance was just complicated per se (I know many educated people in their 30's that share that thinking), and given he trusted this man it may have sound as a good decision at that moment. Now... He is getting older and I would like to be sure he's not being fouled. Convincing him is on me and I know that could happen if I had a clear plan of what to do after.

Answer (score 4):

Pershing is a respected custodian and there are no concerns about Pershing taking/misappropriating your grandfather's money.

However, the advisor and the broker *could* withdraw money from your grandfather's account if he signed paperwork authorizing them to do so.  The only way to be certain is to review copies of the documents your GF signed when opening this account.

The most basic type of account is a **non-discretionary account**.  This only allows the advisor/broker to place a buy or sell order for securities and only after getting your GF's permission.  Only your GF can withdraw money from the account.

**Limited Discretion** is the next level; the main difference is that the advisor/broker can place buy/sell orders without getting your GF's permission.  This is common.  Only your GF can withdraw money from the account.

**Full Discretion** is very similar to being a Power of Attorney(POA); it's likely your GF would have signed a document providing limited POA authority to the advisor/broker.  This gives them the ability to withdraw funds from the account.  This would typically be done to purchase real estate or other non-tradable securities.

Pershing will require a written letter of instruction/authorization to send money to an address other than your GF's address of record, or your GF's bank.  However, if your GF granted Full Discretion it is possible for an unethical person to send money to a 3rd party address or bank.

All advisors and brokers in the US are required to be registered and their disciplinary history can be found here:  https://brokercheck.finra.org/

Check Uruguay's Securities Regulator for something similar - I assume they are required to be registered there as well but only know how US and EU securities markets work.  I found the below site but as an english only reader I can't say with certainty how helpful this will be.

https://www.bcu.gub.uy/Ingles/Paginas/Securities-Intermediaries.aspx

Comment: Of course, the grandfather could have just given this guy "he knew from his neighbourhood" his username and password.

Comment: true, but that would only allow him to send money to the address or bank of record on the account, not a third party address or bank.  Risk is very limited

Comment: We don't know what documents the grandfather signed when handing over the money.  Heck, the address of record might be the adviser's office.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The brokeage firm is listed there.

Comment: What if I contact this firm on my gf behalf? Should they be able to tell me my gf account historical movements if they had my gf consent?

Comment: To comply with anti money laundering and OFAC regulations, pershing requires a drivers license or passport or similar legal document to open an account.  The address on those documents is the address of record.  To use a different address would require specific discretion documentation

Comment: Luis - your best bet is to be on the phone with your GF and have him identify himself and that you are there to speak on his behalf to help him understand his account.  They should be fully accepting of this; if they aren't then that is all you need to know about their trustworthiness.  You can contact Pershing directly to freeze the account and inform them of suspected fraud.  You can likely fax a doc in to remove everyone but your GF from having authority for the account.  Pershing will require your GF to identify himself before they'll tell you anything

Comment: Elder abuse is a key focus of securities regulators, which Pershing will be sensitive to.  If you're getting nowhere with other attempts then tell Pershing you suspect elder abuse